# Plot subset of column using base R

Tags: r, subset

I have a vector:

```
a <- c(1:100)
```

If I'd like to plot a subset of this data, I do this:

```
hist(a[a<40])
```

However, if the vector a is a column of a data frame, this code does not work, i. e.:

```
b <- c(101:200)
c <- rep("A", 100)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

Then this

```
hist(df$a[df$a<40])
```

gives me this error message:

```
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I have googled for a while but cannot figure out the problem. I would like to solve this using base R. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't have a `data.frame` you have a `matrix`. Which can be subseted e.g. with `df[,"a"]` and not with `df$a`.

Comment: `cbind`  returns a matrix not a `data.frame`. You can use `cbind.data.frame`

Comment: Ok, my bad, I usually use data frames. I edited the question.

Comment: It's still a matrix...See the comments above

Comment: Now you have a `character` `matrix`.

Comment: I see. So what if I have a csv file which I imported. It contains many many columns, numeric, factor, etc. all kinds. That is a data frame, right? What code do I need to apply then?

Comment: For a `data.frame` `hist(df$a[df$a<40])` should work.

Comment: It doesn't. However, `hist(df$a[df$a<40,])` works, though.

Comment: `df$a[df$a<40,]` will not work. `df[df$a<40,]` or `df[df$a<40, "a"]` will work but might return something different.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a `data.frame`, you could use the following code:

```
a <- c(1:100)
b <- c(101:200)
c <- rep("A", 100)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
with(df[df$a < 40,], hist(a))
```

Output:

[image]